# What could cause an EC2 instance to fail to be added to an Elastic Load Balancer/fail the Health Check?

Tags: tomcat, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I'll do my best to provide a MCVE without drowning you in the details.

I recently spun up two EC2 instances to serve as Tomcats that were launched as clones of an existing one. I also created an Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) to sit in front of these Tomcat instances to manage requests to my web app. Both EC2 instances are, as far as I can tell, essentially identical. They both share a security group, are listening on port 8080, etc.

When I went to add the instances to the ELB, one was successful, but one was not. The error indicated was:

```
Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of HealthChecks consecutively.
```

On the EC2 Instance list, the individual health of both Tomcats reports fine, and I can ssh to them both. I've confirmed that the Tomcat service is running on both, and a netstat -alnt shows both are listening to the 8080 port. Restarting the problem instance and re-adding it to the ELB did not help.

Below are my health check settings which apply to both instances:

```
Ping Target HTTP:8080/
Timeout      5 seconds
Interval    30 seconds
Unhealthy threshold 5
Healthy threshold   10
```

Upping the timeout doesn't seem to have helped. I'm convinced there must be some subtle setting/difference preventing the ELB from discovering the problem instance, but I've Googled around and haven't had any success with any of the suggestions for my specific case.

If any other information would be useful in diagnosing the issue, please let me know.

Comment: do the have same security grp? are there any instance level firewalls running? can you hit the heathcheck endpoint directly from another instance?

Comment: Change that "Ping Target HTTP:8080/" to "Ping Target TCP:8080/" in ELB or in short use TCP protocol instead of HTTP it will work

Comment: @error2007s Wow, that did the trick! I'm curious, why did using HTTP cause one to be accepted but not the other? What's the root cause? Anyway, if you post your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change that `"Ping Target HTTP:8080/"` to `"Ping Target TCP:8080/"` in ELB or in short use TCP protocol instead of HTTP it will work.

If you use HTTP method always make sure you mention a test file like "/test.html" instead of just a "/".

Adding more information for my question here.

How health checks work is that an HTTP or HTTPS GET request is issued to the instance on the ping port and the ping path [1]. If the load balancer receives any response other than "200 OK" within the response timeout period, the instance is considered unhealthy.  For requests containing only a path of '/'  , it is left to your webserver to handle what is known as a  "trailing slash" redirect.  For instance,  Apache will redirect a trailing slash to the resource specified by its DirectoryIndex directive [2].

Documents:
[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-healthchecks.html
[2] https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: Sorry to so this, but -1 for dangerous advice.  You have potentially now declared an instance as healthy that is in fact not healthy -- for example, what if it's failing the health check because it can't connect to a database to render a response for `GET /`?  There is almost certainly an underlying problem that **this change will mask**. *"If you use HTTP method always make sure you mention a test file like "/test.html" instead of just a "/"."* is overly broad. You don't want to test a static file if the instance's "health" should be determined from its ability to do something more complex.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot This is not a dangerous advice this is the correct advice. If the person is not planning to use a "test.html" he should always use TCP Ping Protocol to the port. When a ELB does the health checks using HTTP Ping Protocol it just looks for "HTTP 200" it does not care if the EC2 instance is connecting to DB or not so if we keep the path "/" some times the web server gives the "HTTP 200" (99 % time the instance will not pass the health check due to "/" and it will mark a health instance unhealthy).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Adding a File makes sure ELB gets "HTTP 200" regularly and user has not to worry about connection between ELB and the EC2 instance. So just in case if autoscaling group launches 4-5 instances due to heavy traffic on the application and if user has "/" instead of "test.html" in the path and if only one passes the test (as in above case) other instances gets marked as unhealthy and whole traffic is directed to just one instance which will take the whole application down.

Comment: *makes sure ELB gets 200 OK regularly* **is the wrong objective**... it's like studying for the test instead of learning the material.  ELB should never get 200 OK unless the instance is ready, willing, and able to serve new application requests, everything loaded, running, all external resources (like the database) accessible and available.  Checks should be meaningful -- not just "there's *something* listening on port x, so presumably we can start throwing requests at it" -- which is the only thing TCP checks accomplish.   They do not evaluate the actual health of a web application server.

Comment: Why are you bringing up external resources to which EC2 instances are connected? You know right even if EC2 instance is not able to connect to Database it will still give a 200 OK to ELB when we use HTTP Ping Protocol .

Comment: Not true, if correctly designed. As I have said, a healthcheck should mean something more than "Hello, I am a web server."  The application should be designed to deliberately fail the ELB check if the instance is not ready, by returning a 5XX error, or timing out, or something.  But even if that isn't designed-in, in the case of this question, there is a *reason* the application is failing the check.  It may be by accident rather than design but it suggests this instance is not ready to go in service -- else, why isn't it working like the other one?  Your answer will lead to false positives.